# RC0 Denali - Adding BI Time Intelligence - Error: a time dimension is required in order to add time intelligence

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012, ssas

Currently, working with Denali RC0 and unable to add BI Time Intelligence to the cube.  I have checked the types of the hierachy (type years) and dimension (type time) and created the Time Dimension via the wizard (defaults).

I have scoured the web and have had no luck finding any info regarding this issue other than checking the types associated with the dimension and its hierarchies.  (I have done this)

So, basically, I am unable to add the time intelligence component to my cube.  I feel as if i am missing a basic step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reviewing my dimensions, I realized that I didn't have my time dimension correctly linked into my dimension that had dates.  This was stopping me from adding time intelligence.  Hopefully, this helps someone else out.